# Google Chrome writing problem -- freezes up during typing

Tags: 10.10, google-chrome

I use Google chrome sometimes for googling.  My problem occurs when I am entering text like a username, or comments. in the middle of writing, the typing progress freezes.  To continue writing I have to minimize and then maximize google chrome. Is there any solution for this?

I use 9.0.597.94 (73967) I also face this problem on the previous version to extensions yes I have the following extensions: Auto Copy, csscan, Firebug Lite for Google Chrome, RemindMe, and Virtual Keyboard (by Google). Yes I use Ubuntu standalone.

Additional details:

- Using an Ubuntu 10.10 (English)
- [output of `ps wwaux`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/593478/) (active processes)
- [output of `dpkg -l`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/593480/) (installed packages)

Comment: Can you please spellcheck your query?  It's a bit hard to comprehend.

Comment: Does this also happen in the chromium browser?  Or in beta releases of Chrome?

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i face this problem on both versions.

Comment: Try to start Chrome from the command line in incognito mode (e.g., run `google-chrome  --incognito` and see if it sends any errors to your terminal screen) when you are seeing the problem.

Comment: no error reporting.

Comment: A few questions to hopefully help narrow this down...

 - What version of Chrome are you using?
 - Do you have any extensions installed?
 - Do you use Ubuntu standalone or in a virtual machine?

Comment: What version: i have use 9.0.597.94 (73967) i also face this problem on the previous version to  extensions yes i have the following extensions:- Auto Copy, csscan, Firebug Lite for Google Chrome, RemindMe, and Virtual Keyboard (by Google). Yes i user Ubuntu standalone.

Comment: @craig zheng I think you can deleted it your answer so that this question will display on unanswered section.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving the cause of this Achu? I seem to be experiencing the same thing, but I don't want to switch to Chromium.

Comment: @Achu Has to be something in the settings or extensions... I tried deleting my chrome profile and resyncing to no avail. Do you experience anything like this in other apps? I sometimes have a similar problem when messaging using Pidgin, but not nearly as often. This may or may not be related.

Comment: @VoY No i only experincing this problem on Google chrome and also chromium.

Comment: I'm using the latest Ubuntu as of 2012 and SCIM and this problem still hasn't been solved. I'm trying the work around of exiting SCIM for now. I need it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Disable your spelling checker. Even on my machine, it will freeze for a second when I'm typing something with spellchecking enabled.</del>

The only other issue I can think of is an input method. I see `scim` in your packages and processes list. Try uninstalling it by running:

```
 sudo apt-get purge scim
```

Comment: @Lekensteyn that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What language is you OS / Chromium?

Comment: @Lekensteyn English

Comment: @Achu: Are you running the latest Ubuntu version with up-to-date packages? Just for debugging, can you post a list of active processes by running `ps wwaux` and installed applications by running `dpkg -l` (post it on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ if it gets large).

Comment: @Lekensteyn yes i'm running the latest version. here is the outputs:- `ps wwaux` http://paste.ubuntu.com/593478/ `dpkg -l` http://paste.ubuntu.com/593480/

Comment: @Achu: I think it's your input method causing problems then. If you do not have to enter special, non-latin characters (Chinese, Cyrillic, ..), you can uninstall it safely. It's not installed by default.

Comment: @Lekensteyn  ohhh... I really need scim  I also configured with my local fonts. i don't know what to do now. if that the cause  i will try it after i finished my work on using scim.

Comment: @Achu: Instead of uninstalling it, can you try starting Chrome with `GTK_IM_MODULE=gtk-im-context-simple google-chrome` ? It should disable SCIM for it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I tested more existing scim it works normal! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Lekensteyn  Just saw that you had solved this old one -- nice!

Comment: @jgbelacqua: Actually, it's a workaround. I have not found a bug report, but it would be either a bug in scim or chromium-browser.